# Fragment in MVVMCross

Tags: c#, xamarin, mvvmcross

I have a navigation drawer, and it has list of items, and one them called `CustomPreference`. When user clicks on it, it opens the corresponding view but it is shows an `activity`, but I am trying to have that page as a `fragment`. I wonder what I am missing in my implementation.

**CustomPreferenceView.axml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:background="#CECECE">
</LinearLayout>
```

**CustomPreferenceView.cs**

```
[MvxFragment(typeof(MainViewModel), Resource.Id.MainViewContainer)]
[Register("myapp.android.views.CustomPreferenceView")]
public class CustomPreferenceView: MvxFragment<CustomPreferenceViewModel>
{
    public override View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        var ignored = base.OnCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
        var view = this.BindingInflate(Resource.Layout.CustomPreferenceView, null);
        return view;
    }
}
```

**CustomPreferenceViewModel.cs**

```
public class CustomPreferenceViewModel: MvxViewModel
{

}
```

I can simply illustrate what I want to achieve as follows:

[image]

**MenuView.cs**

```
public bool OnNavigationItemSelected(IMenuItem item)
{
  Navigate(item.ItemId);
  return true;
}

private async Task Navigate(int selectedId)
{
   ((MainView)Activity).DrawerLayout.CloseDrawers();
   await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(320));

   switch (selectedId)
   {
     case Resource.Id.logout:
         ViewModel.ShowLogoutCommand.Execute();
         break;
     case Resource.Id.custompreference:
         ViewModel.ShowCustomPreferenceCommand.Execute();
         break;
   }
}
```

**MainViewModel.cs**

```
public IMvxCommand ShowCustomPreferenceCommand
{
  get { return new MvxCommand(ShowCustomPreference); }
}

private void ShowCustomPreference()
{
   ShowViewModel<CustomPreferenceViewModel>();
}
```

**MainView.axml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/MainViewDrawer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/MainViewContainer"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" />
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/NavigationViewContainer"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="320dp"/>
     </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

**MainView.cs**

```
public class MainView : MvxCachingFragmentCompatActivity<MainViewModel>
 {
    public DrawerLayout DrawerLayout;

    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.MainView);

        DrawerLayout = FindViewById<DrawerLayout>(Resource.Id.MainViewDrawer);
        ViewModel.ShowMenu();

    }
```

Comment: Post the code for the Activity that hosts your `CustomPreferenceView Fragment`

Comment: Do you have 2 views with CustomPreferenceViewModel? One as fragment and one as Activity? Because that would prove why it shows as fragment.

Comment: @Martijn00 I only want to have CustomPreferenceView as a fragment on the top of MainView as shown in the image in the question.

Comment: @hotspring, what does your MainView Activity and layout look like?

Comment: Just to confirm, so you want `CustomPreferenceView`  to open as a fragment in the activity that is already active and has a navigation drawer? What does the command look like that you are using to navigate to the `CustomPreferenceViewModel`?

Comment: Yes, you are correct. I have navigationdrawer menu. I have added more information, please see my update

Comment: All seems fine, what does you MainView Activity and layout (frame where the fragment is being placed) look like? I'm assuming this Activity is using  `MainViewModel`?

Comment: could you please elaborate little bit?

Comment: I have added `Main.axml` as well, please see update

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112320/discussion-between-placehold3r-and-hotspring).

Comment: Please see my update